# How to set Value Input field Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, dom, input, ionic2, refresh

I have a tiny question.

I'm using this HTML code:

```
<ion-input id="amount" type="number" ></ion-input>
```

`<button (click)="setinput()">Set Value</button>`

And this TS code:

```
setinput(){
var input= document.getElementById("amount") as HTMLInputElement;
input.value=42;
console.log("amount");
console.log(input.value);
}
```

My console tells me, that the number got changed. But the updated value wont be displayed in my input field. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance!

L. Trembon

Answer (score 30):

You can do it like that:

page.html

```
<ion-input id="amount" type="number" [(ngModel)]="value"></ion-input>
<button (click)="setInput()">Set Value</button>
```

page.ts

```
export class Page {
  value: number = 0; // Default is 0

  constructor() {}

  setInput() {
    this.value = 42;
  }
}
```

By using `[(ngModel)]="value"` you bind the `value` variable to that input field. That way it is always updated. If you change it in the UI, it is immediately updated "in the code". And when you update it in your code, it automatically updates in the UI.

You should probably read an Angular 2 tutorial before you continue working on your app. Angular provides many tools to make that sort of thing a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly fine. But somehow it adds the ng-valid class if its filled. Can i avoid this?

Comment: I don't know how you can avoid this. They added it to help with input validation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Spent half a day searching for this answer! Thank you.